# How to compare column values in Scheme

Tags: sql, database, scheme

I've never worked with scheme before.

I have to iterate over a table column to ensure all the values in the result set are the same. If all the values are equal, then I'll write they have been checked.

Lets say I have a db table called Car with a column called TirePressure. The select statement will return 4 TirePressure values. If the values are all the same, I need to write a result.

```
(if (zero? (gSelectOne stmt (string-append "SELECT TirePressure FROM Car WHERE VIN = "ABCDEF")))
     (if (= 48 (gGetInt (stmt "TirePressure")))
       (begin (gSetIntValue (mCtl "TiresChecked") 1))
    )
```

Please ignore the db violations, this is just an example.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` is a special form (fancy lisp talk for non function, like `if` and `while` in any other language) that takes 3 expressions, a `predicate`, a `consequent` and an `alternative`. Like this:

```scm
(if predicate
    consequent
    alternative)
```

Every expression returns a value so if the predicate is not `#f` (thus true) the `consequent` is evaluated and is the result of the code. If not the evaluation of teh alternative is the result.

Imagine you want to check if the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are zero you can do like this:

```scm
(= 0 a b c) ; ==> #t/#f
```

So imagine the have an expression that becomes a list of prerssures we can just make a variable `res` for it:

```scm
(define res '(0 0 0))
(if (apply = 0 res)
    "all zero"
    "not good")
; ==> "all zero"
```